# Dropzone.js only uploading two files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I've been having a battle with dropzone.js. No matter what setting I change the plugin will only upload one or two of the files dragged into the dropzone.

Interestingly enough though if I step through all the code using debugger points I can see it going through and uploading each file. And they do upload. Every one of them.

Could this be the plugin working faster than the backend? It is getting to the success function each time so this has be utterly confused.

I have tried all the tricks.

I have the paralleUplads and maxFiles set

```
parallelUploads: 5,
maxFilesize: 5,
maxFiles: 5,
```

and I have tried setting these in the init section as well for the queue section as well

```
init: function() {
    this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
      this.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
    });

    this.on("processing", function() {
       this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
    });
 },
```

Without the added code above my dropzone function looks like this

```
 $(".somediv").dropzone({
                url: 'someurl',
                async: false,
                clickable: false,
                sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
                        var fileType = file.type;
                        var form_data = new FormData(file);
                        fileType = fileType.substring(fileType.indexOf("/") + 1);
                        formData.append("data", file);
                        formData.append("documentID", 0);
                        formData.append("dataTypeCode", fileType);
                        formData.append("dataDescription", file.name);
                        formData.append('filepart', form_data)

                },
                addedfile: function(file) {
                    var _this = this,
                        reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        _this.processQueue()
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                },
                success: function(data) {

                    var fileType = data.type;
                    fileType = fileType.substring(fileType.indexOf("/") + 1);
                    iconImg(fileType)
                    console.log('uploaded ' + data)

                    var statusCode = 'AD'
                    var text = "'Attachment Added' by " + currentUser.employeeId
                    statusCodeChange(statusCode, brCode, incidentId, text)
                    var randomNum = Math.random() * 20
                    table.row.add({
                            "dataDescription": data.name,
                            "dataTypeCode": fileType,
                            "documentTimeStamp": formatDate(new Date()),
                            "documentID": randomNum
                        }).draw(false)
                        .node();
                    growl("Attachment Uploaded!", {});
                }
            });
```

Comment: I've tested the code as you have it, dropping 10 files it uploads 10 files. I am not sure what is that you are asking. Are the files received correctly in the backend? Are the previews showing correctly? What are you expecting that is not happening?

Comment: @wallek876, You were able to upload ten files? That's not happening for me. I can drag 5 files in and it will only upload 2 or 3 of them. Which it strange because I get the preview for all 5, but when navigating away and coming back fewer than 5 will be there. I would expect all 5 to be there.

Comment: yeah, all files are uploaded. I think the problem you are having may be related to backend part.

Comment: @wallek876, I was thinking that at first as well, however I tested the same backend code with a traditional upload button and it worked fine with multiple.